# How do I get crtdbg.h file?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I am using [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) GCC + [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) on Windows, and I have run into this error:

> C:\Program Files\ITG Derivatives LLC\api_clear-2.0.2.48\include/windows/csassert.h:12:20: fatal error crtdbg.h No such file or directory

What is the `crtdbg.h` file? How can I get it and solve this problem?

Answer (score 24):

I ran into this exact same issue, but with Visual Studio Community Edition 2019.

The solution was to download the Windows 10 SDK using the Visual Studio installer.  Once I did that the next compile worked fine.

The header file "crtdbg.h" is part of the Windows 10 SDK kit. I believe you will find crtdbg.h located here C:\Program Files... or C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\crtdbg.h depending on your setup and version.

Comment: Definitely worth checking this out first before trying the above solution.

Answer (score 14):

`<crtdbg.h>` is a Microsoft Visual C++ specific header. You may be able to work around this problem using a stub similar to the following:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <crtdbg.h>
#else
#define _ASSERT(expr) ((void)0)

#define _ASSERTE(expr) ((void)0)
#endif
```

Note that this will disable any asserts in the code you are compiling against, and still won't help you if the code you're compiling uses more advanced features inside `crtdbg.h`, such as memory leak detection. If these features are in use, you will need to compile the code with MSVC++ rather than MinGW.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same issue, but with Visual Studio Code. 
First start/restart VS Installer and install the Win10 SDK.
Then restart your computer and the needed heasers are available.

Comment: Is there any reason why it did not working in the first place?

Comment: Some system changes will take after reboot. Search Directories were upated and the file crtdbg.h could be found by VS Code and VS Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Go--g-- search here.

After installing Visual Studio 2019 preview(2022 preview), I have faced the same.

Opening `Developer Command Prompt` and after going to a particular folder,

`cl test.cpp` gave above error.

**Resolve :**

After installing **Visual Studio 2022 preview** or any other version, do `reboot` the system.

After rebooting, I could successfully, run the `cl` command, and compiled a test program without any of the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently by trying to install LLVM/Visual Studio Code.
It seems that the Windows SDK installation is required for the clang compiler.

To install the Windwos SDK open/download the Visual Studio Installer and select the "Windows 10 SDK" checkbox in the "Desktop in development with C++" toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Windows SDK, and still have this error, go to project propreties -> VC++ -> Include Directories. then paste C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include(Version)\ucrt

Answer (score 0):

Just note that I got the same error in Visual Studio 2022 installed on Win 10 Version 21H2. Solution was to install latest Windows 10 SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) and then restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, I tried updating the SDK through Visual Studio as mentioned above to no avail. One thing I did was used an old PC to download the SDK, transferred the contents via USB. Took the File directory that Visual Studio was looking in, and copied everything over from the downloaded SDK in the USB to that file path/directory as mentioned in Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by copy pasting all the files from:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt

to the folder indicated in the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).