# Having problems with mingw32-make to make googletest

Tags: cmake, mingw, googletest

This is my current environment.
Windows 10 64bit, MinGW, CMake 3.15.2, Python 3.7.
I downloaded googletest from https://github.com/google/googletest.

I ran cmake and the following is the output.

```
C:\googletest-master>cd build

C:\googletest-master\build>cmake ../ -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/sangjin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe (found version "3.7.4")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/googletest-master/build
```

But when I ran mingw32-make I got the following error message.

```
C:\googletest-master\build>mingw32-make
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[ 12%] Building CXX object googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
In file included from C:\googletest-master\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:41:
C:/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest.cc:86:11: fatal error: crtdbg.h: No such file or directory
 # include <crtdbg.h>  // NOLINT
           ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
googletest\CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:171: recipe for target 'googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:139: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

C:\googletest-master\build>
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem.

Comment: The `crtdbg.h` is a Visual Studio file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685202/how-do-i-get-crtdbg-h-file)). Did you clean your CMake cache before building with mingw, or use a different CMake build folder for the mingw build? Also, please **copy/paste** the actual output instead of using pictures/images on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I was aware of it and tried to solve crtdbg.h problem by editing gtest.cc using the link but other header files related visual studio such as debugapi.h are still causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, the `gtest.cc` file includes the `crtdbg.h` header, and you can edit the file to try to fix the issue. But that header was likely included for a reason. Is Visual Studio installed on the machine in which you are running mingw?

Comment: No.  I have not installed visual studio in my machine.

Comment: It seems like, based on the contents of `gtest.c`, that it is assumed that all Windows environments have some form of Visual Studio C++ packages installed.

Comment: Do you mean I have to install visual studio to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, that would be one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This version of google test doesn't have that issue, try to build it
https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/216c37f057ae0fff38062984c890df912f40ccf6

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for

- **mingw32-base** version **2013072200**
- **mingw32-gcc-g++** version **6.3.0-1**
- **gtest** version **1.10.0**

In **...\googletest\src\gtest.cc**

first at (original) line 86, make header inclusion conditional to MSC toolchain using *#ifdef _MSC_VER ... #endif* preprocessor macros.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# include <crtdbg.h>  // NOLINT
# include <debugapi.h>  // NOLINT
#endif // _MSC_VER
```

then at (original) line 4913, make assertion redirection also conditional.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // In debug mode, the Windows CRT can crash with an assertion over invalid
    // input (e.g. passing an invalid file descriptor).  The default handling
    // for these assertions is to pop up a dialog and wait for user input.
    // Instead ask the CRT to dump such assertions to stderr non-interactively.
    if (!IsDebuggerPresent()) {
      (void)_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT,
                              _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
      (void)_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
    }
#endif // _MSC_VER
```

With theese changes, unit tests build and execute as expected.