# Failed building wheel for nes-py

Tags: python, windows, pip, command-prompt, python-wheel

**Info:** I am using Windows 10 with python 3.7.7 and pip 19.2.3

**Problem:** I was trying to install nes-py in cmd prompt using `pip install nes-py`, but during the `Building wheel for nes-py (setup.py) ... error` stage of the install I got the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nes-py
```

**Edit:** I copy and pasted over many files from the Windows SDK and now have a new error:

```
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nes-py
```

Comment: It seems `crtdbg.h` is a header file from Windows SDK. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958134/error-c1083-yvalsh-unable-to-include-crtdbgh.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803149/7976758

Comment: I installed the windows sdk in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` but the error still persisted. The missing file was in the Windows Kits folder though so I copy and pasted it over to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\`. The error then disappeared but I got a new one for a different file. So I then copy and pasted over the entire include folder and lib folder. This made a lot of errors disappear but I got another one which I do not know what to do about. I have added the error message to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). This installed all the needed files for me and allowed me to install any packages that had a wheel. This isn't a very elegant fix since it also installed many files that I do not need, but it seems to work and is very simple.

Comment: What is the relationship between this and node.js? I already have node installed, but did not solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

I only solved this issue by installing [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/vs/community/) (I had Visual Studio Code).

I did this following the comment [here](https://pypi.org/project/nes-py/) about the requirements to install py-nes that are already inside Visual Studio Community.

Answer (score 0):

Try with completely new enviorment using conda `create -n your_env_name python=3.7`. I have created with python 3.7. It resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just download and install this program and run the command again https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the framework/library suggested, explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve the problem - install SDK for Windows 10
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5E4S.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).