# C++ the system cannot find the file specified error

Tags: c++

When i start my code i get 'the system cannot find the file specified' error. What's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoY3I.png   <--- Here is my problem

Comment: The compiler fails to build the exe program. On the bottom of the screen you have the exact cause of failure. It is missing WindowsSDKDir and probably is missing Windows SDK at all. Also I don't understand why main.cpp is in resource folder and not in source folder. You should install Windows SDK first or configure VisualStudio to access it correctly. By the way it is not a C++ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executable did not build. If you look in the console output you have an error: cannot include crtdbg.h. This is the error you have to fix.

This might help: [How do I get crtdbg.h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685202/how-do-i-get-crtdbg-h-file)

Comment: Can you say what i need to do? I cant find the solution.